# Is there a way to determine if a Firebase user's UID is valid?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I am building a server route that I wish to restrict for use only by authenticated users. I plan to send a user.uid with a POST to this route, and I want to validate the UID is one that exists in Firebase. I know I can add UIDs manually in Firebase and check against this data, but is it possible to see what UIDs Firebase authentication is tracking? I think this approach would be better then checking against my own list.

The purpose for this is to ensure that these routes are not accessed with a phony UID (e.g. for malicious purposes).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can check whether a specific UID corresponds to a Firebase Authentication user in your project by using the Firebase Admin SDK on your server. From the [Firebase documentation on retrieving user data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#retrieve_user_data):

```
admin.auth().getUser(uid)
  .then(function(userRecord) {
    // See the UserRecord reference doc for the contents of userRecord.
    console.log("Successfully fetched user data:", userRecord.toJSON());
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error fetching user data:", error);
  });
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 14):

Validating a UID is not enough to block malicious users: 1) the attackers could pretend to be other users by sending other user's UID, and 2) UID never changes or expires, which means there is no way to enforce the users (or attackers) to re-authenticate.

What you need is to pass the Firebase token from client app to your server, and validate the token before accepting it.

- The token is securely signed by Firebase private key. No other party can issue a valid Firebase token.
- The token is valid for only one hour. Firebase server will check the account status (e.g. password change event) before issuing a new token.
- The token payload contains UID and audience. You should verify audience is your own application.

You can use Firebase Admin SDK or third party libraries to verify a Firebase token. See [Firebase doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#verify_id_tokens_using_the_firebase_admin_sdks) for details.

Comment: This is certainly a better method. I will use this method instead of what I was originally considering.

Comment: This is how it should be done. @Jin can you please elaborate how to take a token received from a client and verify it from the backend? I ask because i tried auth.verify_id_token(..) but got 'Auth instance has no attribute 'verify_id_token'

Comment: But if a malicious user creates a new account, he already has a valid token.
You mean if the app needs to hit a backend endpoint, we should do all above 3 points, before accepting the backend call?

Answer (score 0):

A UID is part of the payload when a Firebase user is authenticated to Firebase and is null when a user is not authenticated. You can get the UID upon user authentication. The syntax is different depending on what framework you are working in.

Check out the Firebase API Reference for specific syntax and examples: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/

Answer (score 0):

create a token in your client app

```
private String getAuthTokenAndPost(){
    mAuth.getCurrentUser().getIdToken(false).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<GetTokenResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<GetTokenResult> task) {
            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                String idToken = task.getResult().getToken();
                sendReqToServer(idToken);


            }else{
                Toast.makeText(CartActivity.this, "couldn't generate Token", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });

    return "";
}
```

then use firebase admin SDK on your server side, here is an example of a Node server

```
getAuth()
  .verifyIdToken(idToken)
  .then((decodedToken) => {
    const uid = decodedToken.uid;
    // ...
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // Handle error
  });
```

ID token verification requires a project ID. The Firebase Admin SDK attempts to obtain a project ID via one of the following methods:

1. If the SDK was initialized with an explicit projectId app option, the SDK uses the value of that option.
2. If the SDK was initialized with service account credentials, the SDK uses the project_id field of the service account JSON object.
3. If the GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT environment variable is set, the SDK uses its value as the project ID. This environment variable is available for code running on Google infrastructure such as App Engine and Compute Engine.

check the [document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#android)