# How to verify a user is authenticated and present in firebase, when doing read/write operations on the rest-api, in nodejs, UI is in flutter?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I have built a rest-api using Nodejs and mongodb for the flutter app, works completely fine and i am authenticating user using **firebase phone authentication** and I have some complex work, cannot be handled by the firebase, so setup a restapi for the work, so when user hits that api, **i want to make sure that user is present and authenticated by the firebase before reading and writing from the db, on the server(api) side, written in node js**. How to achieve this, any ideas?

**P.S : I am open for ideas, and thanks for the help in advance :)**

*If anything wrong in doing this or with question, suggest for the edit*

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `currentUser` method of FirebaseAuth to verify if the user is logged in

```dart
FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
if(user!=null){
  // do your thing
}
```

Edit 
In case you want to verify user on your server, use Firebase Admin SDK in your Nodejs server. You will have to pass some identifier like UID, email or phone number; whichever applicable.

```js
admin.auth().getUser(uid)
  .then(function(userRecord) {
    // See the UserRecord reference doc for the contents of userRecord.
    console.log('Successfully fetched user data:', userRecord.toJSON());
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log('Error fetching user data:', error);
  });
```

Reference to the docs for more details : https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users

Comment: Thanks, Fardeen for the answer, i want to verify the user in the rest-api or node js server side, not on the UI side, i.e in the app.

Comment: I think this works, thanks, but anyone with that uid can access it. I have found the some what similar question, answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42476746/13462594 ,

Comment: But couldn't understand the concept of **Firebase token**, and wondering where to get it and for the user.

Comment: You can get the id token from your current user using `user.getIdToken()` and pass it to your server for verification. Use this reference: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#web